# Repeating runs in an experiment to account for randomness and uncontrolled factors

Tags: sample-size, experiment-design

Background: I'm designing an experiment where I have a sequence X of operations for which I want to measure a property (i.e., the overall performance of the sequence). I'd like some input from you to check whether my experimental design is sound.

Since the measurement of the property might be affected by external factors I cannot control, I repeat the execution of each sequence a number of times (say 30, the "magical number" for statistical tests to hold), so that I can assess the performance of the operations in the sequence without bias. Up to here I think the experimental design is sound.

Now consider the case where I want to compare the sequence X with randomly generated sequences. Ideally, I would generate at random a number of sequences (again, say 30), and run each of these for 30 times, for a total of 30*30=900 runs.

Is it really necessary to perform this large number of runs? My gut feeling says that, since the randomness of the generation of the sequence is independent of the randomness of the external factors I cannot control during the measurement, I can probably get away with a smaller number of runs and still retain statistical validity of the conclusions. Can I perhaps just generate 30 random sequences, and execute each one of those only once (because the two layers of randomness - generation and measurement - even out over a large sample)?

What's your take?

Comment: *(say 30, the "magical number" for statistical tests to hold)* There is no such magical number!  Otherwise, this is very abstract ... can you be more concrete, please? What kind of operations? How do you measure the property? ...